# What WS-* standards does BizTalk 2010 support?

Tags: web-services, standards, soa, biztalk, biztalk-2010

Despite spending some time trawling the MS websites, I have not been able to find out precisely what WS-* standards (and what versions) are supported by BizTalk 2010. The BizTalk site is curiously light on that sort of detail. Any idea how I find out, or am I asking the wrong question? Should I simply ask what standards are supported by WCF? If so, which version of that should I be paying attention to, or does it not matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some useful information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259952%28v=bts.70%29.aspx).

> WCF-WSHttp adapter. Provides the WS-* standards support over the HTTP transport. The WCF-WSHttp adapter implements the following specifications: WS-Transaction for the transactional interactions between external applications and the MessageBox database, and WS-Security for message security and authentication. The transport is HTTP or HTTPS, and message encoding is a Text or Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism (MTOM) encoding.

Also found some further specification [here](http://blog.paul.somers.com/blog/_archives/2009/11/3/4370233.html). Here's the complete list for the WsHttp binding:

- WS-Reliability
- WS-Reliable WS-Security
- WS-SecureConversation
- WS-Trust
- WS-Federation
- WS-Addressing
- WS-Policy
- WS-MetadataExchange
- WS-Coordination WS-Atomic

Comment: thanks, but this is only a partial answer. does this support come from WCF and is that all there is? i suspect there's more...

Comment: Updated post with more details

Comment: Thank You. That's exactly what I was after. I wonder where Paul Somers got the details from. I'll ask him direct, then add any URLs he can give me to your (accepted) answer.